# Getting syntax error at or near "FROM" while updating a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

```
junk=# select * from t;                                                                                                                                
   name   | intval 
----------+--------
 bar2  |      2
 bar3  |      3
 bar4  |      4
(3 rows)
```

and

```
junk=# select * from temp;                                                                                                                             
 id |    name    | intval 
----+------------+--------
  1 | foo   |      0
  2 | foo2  |      2
  3 | foo3  |      3
  4 | foo4  |      4
  5 | foo5  |      5
(5 rows)
```

Now, I want to use the values from `table t` to update the values in `table temp`. Basically, I want to replace the name column in second, third and fourth values in temp by bar2, bar3 and bar4.

I created the table t using the COPY statement. I am doing batch updates and I am trying to optimize that.

So, I get this error. I think this is pretty basic one.

```
junk=# UPDATE temp FROM t SET name=t.name FROM t WHERE intval=t.intval;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: UPDATE temp FROM t SET name=t.name FROM t WHERE intval=t.int...
                    ^
junk=#
```

Fow now, this works.

```
UPDATE test SET name=t.name FROM t WHERE test.intval=t.intval
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of your first FROM t clause.

FROM must come after SET, not before and it can only affect the WHERE clause.  SET must be done with subqueries.

your completed code is:

```
UPDATE temp SET name=(SELECT t.name FROM t WHERE temp.intval = t.inval);
```

PostgreSQL has some ways to optimize this so it's not like you are just doing a huge nested loop join (and looking up one row over and over from the heap based on the join criteria).

Edit:  Adding plan to show we are not, in fact, running through a sequential scan of the second table for each row on the first one.

Here is an example that updates 172 rows in one table using a group-by from another:

```
mtech_test=# explain analyze
update ap
set amount = (select sum(amount) from acc_trans ac where ac.trans_id = ap.id) + 1;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Update on ap  (cost=0.00..3857.06 rows=229 width=231) (actual time=39.074..39.0
   74 rows=0 loops=1)
 ->  Seq Scan on ap  (cost=0.00..3857.06 rows=229 width=231) (actual time=0.050..28.444 rows=172 loops=1)
     SubPlan 1
       ->  Aggregate  (cost=16.80..16.81 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=0.109..0.110 rows=1 loops=172)
             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on acc_trans ac  (cost=4.28..16.79 rows=4 width=5) (actual time=0.075..0.102 rows=4 loops=172)
                   Recheck Cond: (trans_id = ap.id)
                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on acc_trans_trans_id_key  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=4 loops=172)
                         Index Cond: (trans_id = ap.id)
Trigger for constraint ap_entity_id_fkey: time=69.532 calls=172
Trigger ap_audit_trail: time=391.722 calls=172
Trigger ap_track_global_sequence: time=1.954 calls=172
Trigger check_department: time=111.301 calls=172
Total runtime: 612.001 ms
(13 rows)
```

`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without `SELECT` statement?

Comment: If you are worried about bad plans, take heart, the planner does a good job of avoiding that.  I will edit to add a plan if you'd like.

Comment: I attached the plan above.  Note that it shows that most of the time in that query is actually spent updating the table.  The select portion is remarkably minor.  Also in 9.1 you can use WITH to encapsulate a select for subsequent re-use if you need to correlate.  I don't have a lot of experience with this however.  I suspect it would be a net win if you are querying a lot from the same table.  It would not be as good if you are not.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I am actually new to SQL and postgres. I was just trying to learn the options available. As stupid it may sound, I just learned how to analyse the queries. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I copied too much:

`UPDATE temp SET name=(SELECT t.name FROM t WHERE temp.intval = t.inval);`

Of you want to filter you can also:

`UPDATE temp SET name=(SELECT t.name FROM t WHERE temp.intval = t.inval) FROM t WHERE t.intval = temp.intval`

Sorry about that.

Comment: Interestingly in my tests, adding the where clause speeds up the query dramatically despite a much more complicated plan and same number of records updated (all of them).  My guess is this has to do with running scan on the joining table first so disk i/o may be minimized.  This performance gain interestingly works even on subsequent runs so it is probably a matter of preloading the cache. (Subsequent runs of the ap query being 200 ms or so, with the where clause being approx 75 ms.)

Comment: In the PostgreSQL 9.1 manual, the outline syntax for the UPDATE statement is:  `[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]`.  You may be able to do it with a FROM clause without an explicit SELECT, but the FROM clause does not go where you are getting the syntax error reported.